# Adding Accessory to Home using HomeKit in iOS 8

Tags: ios, homekit

I was able to create home and add rooms but when trying to add accessory to the home as,

```
- (IBAction)addAccessory:(id)sender {
    [myHome addAccessory:myAccessory completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@ accessory successfully added to %@ home",
                  myAccessory.name, myHome.name);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"addAccessory error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

}
```

an alert is shown with the message "Enter setup code for bulb" with a textfield and two buttons but the textfield is not allowing to enter the setup code.When clicked on "SetUp" button alert is dismissed without performing any action and when "cancel" is selected,It's going to error block showing the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error -70890.)".

The delegate method "didFindNewAccessory" is printing the accessory.services as empty.

```
-(void)accessoryBrowser:(HMAccessoryBrowser*)browser didFindNewAccessory:
(HMAccessory*)accessory {
    NSLog(@"Accessory discovered is %@",accessory);
    NSLog(@"Accessory services is %@",accessory.services);
}
```

Example:
Accessory discovered is [ name = lock, identifier = D8946530-BCD9-4244-AB49-AF507105CC73 ]
Accessory services is ( )

Comment: I understand that you're new to StackOverflow, so you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/tour so that you can realise to up-vote and "accept" correct answers. This helps others in the community to find the better answers.

Answer (score 1):

From where are you calling your `addAccessory:(id)sender` method?
You can do it in the `didFindNewAccessory`: method to add the discovered devices since it gets called for every device that got discovered.

I suppose the variable `myAccessory` is a property? I don´t see you setting it in the method as instance variable or using it in the method or as parameter. It might be uninitialised if you didn't initialise it manually.

Another possibility is that you didm´t set any service in the HomeKit Accessory Simulator. That would explain why you get a description for the device but don´t get any services.

Could you add some more code to show where you are creating myAccessory and call your methods?

EDIT:
I had the same problem where it worked but then somehow stopped working. I wasn't able to enter the setup code and googled a bit. The solution was to open the iOS simulator and uncheck the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" option in the hardware -> keyboard menu. After that a number keyboard should appear which lets you enter the code.